# JQuery adding the values of a column given a column name

Tags: jquery, html-table

Let's say I have a table :

```
    <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <th> Col1 </th>
    <th> Col2 </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
       <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

And I want to add the values in column named **Col2**, which is 4. I don't want to add the values by the position of the column, which is [answered here](http://naspinski.net/post/Use-jQuery-to-add-all-the-values-in-a-table-column_.aspx), since the position of the column is variable.

Comment: so what is it based on? the fact that the text content of the header column is Col2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index = $('table th:contains(Col2)').index(),   // get index of th
    sum = 0;
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt( $.trim( $('td:eq('+ index +')', this).text() ), 10);
});
```

#### A little explanation

---

- `$('td:eq('+ index +')', this).text()` get the text of corresponding td
- `$.trim( $('td:eq('+ index +')', this).text() )` removing spaces from text
- `parseInt( $.trim( $('td:eq('+ index +')', this).text() ), 10)` converts the value of integet
- `sum += parseInt( $.trim( $('td:eq('+ index +')', this).text() ), 10);` performing the sum.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h3nVH/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var colNum = $('th').filter(function(){
                 return $(this).text().trim() == 'Col2';
             }).index(),
    sum = 0;

$('tbody tr').each(
    function(i){
        colValue = $(this).find('td').eq(colNum).text();
        sum += parseInt(colValue);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gcLqL/).

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column index with

```
var columnIndex = $("#myTable th").index(":contains('Col2')");
```

From there, you can use the snippet you linked in your question to collect the sum and output the result to some total cell.

```
var sum = 0;
$("#myTable tbody tr").each(function() {
    var td = $("> td", this).eq(columnIndex);
    sum += td.text() | 0;
});
```

Note: `x | 0` is a little trick to convert to an integer.

Comment: @dharm0us D'oh, I typed `#mytable` instead of `#myTable`. Damn you, case sensitivity!